# django messages TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: django

I've been trying to use messages in django.
I checked everything but keep getting this error below.

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /home/
'messages' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
tz
```

I made sure all the settings are properly configured
in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'schedule_app',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

    <h2>
        {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                {% message %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </h2>
```

I also tried {% load messages %}
on top of the template but still not working..

Answer (score 2):

The message is a variable, not a template tag, so you should use `{{ … }}`, not <s>`{% … %}`</s>:

```
<h2>
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            {{ message }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</h2>
```

Comment: oh yeah ty! but still giving me the same error :(

Comment: @KeeYu: the same? Are you sure that you have fixed it in *all* templates and that the error message is about the same template tag? Normally the error should locate where in the template. You probably should also restart the server (and `{% load messages %}` probably is also not valid).

Comment: omg lol all I had to do was restart the server... thank you so much. I'm still a noob at web dev and I learned something today. thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else restart their server and it doesn't work, here is how I solved it. I did not include {% load messages %}
I added extra_tags='' in the view
messages.success(request, "Child has been successfully added.",extra_tags='child')
For the template

```
{% if messages %}
   <ul class="messages">
   {% for message in messages %}
     <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{message}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

This way it enables categorization and style messages in a way that is flexible and adaptable to specific needs.